# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter, dart

When updating my flutter to version 3.0.0 , the console started showing me this error

does anyone know how to fix it

AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_api_headers-1.2.0+1\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\zeshuaro\google_api_headers\GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt: (58, 68): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileDebugKotlin'.

Comment: I have the same after upgrade to flutter 3.0 and so far found no solution

Answer (score 2):

As a temporarily solution:-

**Solution 1**

Delete every line of code in GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt file and leave it blank, then add this flutter dependency

`google_api_headers: ^1.3.0`

Some of your packages needs updates so this is a temporary fix while you update your packages or awaiting updates.

**Solution 2**

you open this file producing error GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt (cmd + click on it in console for macOS)
and cut all the try catch part

```
try {
            val info: PackageInfo
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                info = context!!.packageManager.getPackageInfo(call.arguments<String>(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
                for (signature in info.signingInfo.apkContentsSigners) {
                    parseSignature(signature, result)
                }
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                info = context!!.packageManager.getPackageInfo(call.arguments<String>(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                for (signature in info.signatures) {
                    parseSignature(signature, result)
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            result.error("ERROR", e.toString(), null)
        }
```

so if method is empty and doing nothing

```
if (call.method == "getSigningCertSha1") {}else{}
```

then it works, I don't know why but it is a temporary solution, check if your libraries work ok

[check this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103618)

path to the file you should edit on windows os

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_api_headers-1.2.0+1\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\zeshuaro\google_api_headers\GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt
```

**Solution 3**

you could downgrade your flutter version as you wait for the flutter libraries to be fixed

Comment: path to the above file in windows or you can check in your ide error messages         C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_api_headers-1.2.0+1\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\zeshuaro\google_api_headers\GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt

Comment: google_api_headers: ^1.1.0 was a dependency to another package i am using. The problem started after I upgraded flutter to v.3. It was resolved just by adding google_api_headers: ^1.3.0 in my pubspec.yaml